# How do I make store_promo a parameter? so that I can customize when calling the function

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```
calculatePrice(productid, promoTypes, promoidp, qty) {
        this.grandtotal = (this.getProductCart(productid).price - (this.getProductCart(productid).price * (this.getPromo(promoTypes(promoidp).store_promo).amount / 100))) * qty
        console.log(this.grandtotal)
        return this.grandtotal
}
```

**here I will customize it**

```
{{ calculatePrice(items.product_id, getPartner, items.store_id, items.qty) }}
```

Comment: do you mean  the property of `promoTypes(promoidp)` called `store_promo`?

Comment: no, promoTypes(promoidp).**store_promo** <--------------- just this :D

Comment: yes, that's exactly the `store_promo` property of `promoTypes(promoidp)` .... which should be identical to `getPartner(items.store_id).store_promo` where you call that function

Comment: can i customize `.store_promo` in parameters or i shoud take it `getPartner(items.store_id).store_promo` to parameter directly?

Comment: or just put 3 parameters? like

`this.grandtotal = (this.getProductCart(productid).price - (this.getProductCart(productid).price * (this.getPromo(promoTypes / 100))) * qty`

Comment: what do you mean "customize" in parameters? if you need to call getPartner to get an object with store_promo property, then you have to call it somewhere

Comment: if you remove the `promoidp` how will `promoTypes` work?

Comment: I'm confused, is it just like this? :D

`(this.getPromo(promoTypes / 100))) * qty`

Comment: well, no - it'd be `(this.getPromo(store_promo).amount / 100)` because `.amount` is a property of the return value of `this.getPromo` (if your code is correct)

Comment: :( ..... so i have discount we call in indonesian "promo" so we get 2 promo.. store and self product promo.. the problem is .. we cant customize the **.store_promo**.. we want store_promo like parameters.. it cant customize when we call.. my code was right.. but just show product with the store discount cause the **.store_promo** cant change to self

Comment: but i think thanks bro @jaromanda X :D